# How to calculate MaximumDrawdown using Returns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, finance, quantitative-finance

I have DataFrame `final` with returns of my portfolio. I am trying to calculate the MaxDrawdown using the returns. I have tried the below code and did see many stackexchange questions. But not able to solve this. Is there any way possible to calculate the maximum draw down using returns of the portfolio.

```
              Returns
1/2/2009     0.030483579
1/5/2009     0.002872092
1/6/2009     0.01461333
1/7/2009    -0.032431836
1/8/2009     0.0055774
1/9/2009    -0.019844336
1/12/2009   -0.019705618
1/13/2009    0.001093185
1/14/2009   -0.032726765
1/15/2009    0.013635182
1/16/2009    0.009807648
1/20/2009   -0.044440252
1/21/2009    0.035156229
1/22/2009   -0.01460641
1/23/2009    0.007399468
1/26/2009    0.007910521
1/27/2009    0.007848472
1/28/2009    0.028944903
1/29/2009   -0.023816962
1/30/2009   -0.02550717
2/2/2009    -0.000292223
2/3/2009     0.020191091
2/4/2009    -7.93651E-06
2/5/2009     0.020070065
2/6/2009     0.026235957
2/9/2009    -0.001606124
2/10/2009   -0.03629415
2/11/2009    0.00248416
2/12/2009    0.001925152
2/13/2009   -0.00441840
```

Code:

```
cum_returns = (1 + final).cumprod()
drawdown =  1 - final.div(final.cummax())
```

Can anyone help me in solving this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC after `cumprod` adding `diff` and min is the max-draw-down

```
(df.Returns+1).cumprod().diff().min()
Out[316]: -0.043177386133390616
```

Base on the MDD [definition](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/maximum-drawdown-mdd.asp)

```
s=(df.Returns+1).cumprod()
np.ptp(s)/s.max()
Out[319]: 0.11457761692384323
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can a drawdown be negative?? Can you explain more in detail what the code is doing.

Comment: THe calculation I think is drawdown rather than Maximum Drawdown . Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Thanks! SOlved my problem

Answer (score 4):

You can get a dataframe with the maximum drawdown up to the date using `pandas.expanding()`([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html)) and then applying `max` to the window.

`pandas.expanding` will apply a function in the manner [pandas.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) does, but with a window that starts at the beginning of the dataframe and expands up to the current row (more info about the Window Functions [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#window-functions) and [pandas.expanding](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#expanding-windows)):

```
>> cum_returns = (1 + final).cumprod()
>> drawdown =  1 - final.div(final.cummax())
>> drawdown.expanding().max()

            Returns
1/2/2009   0.000000
1/5/2009   0.000000
1/6/2009   0.000000
1/7/2009   0.032432
1/8/2009   0.032432
1/9/2009   0.046343
1/12/2009  0.065136
1/13/2009  0.065136
1/14/2009  0.094742
1/15/2009  0.094742
1/16/2009  0.094742
1/20/2009  0.114578
1/21/2009  0.114578
1/22/2009  0.114578
1/23/2009  0.114578
1/26/2009  0.114578
1/27/2009  0.114578
1/28/2009  0.114578
1/29/2009  0.114578
1/30/2009  0.114578
2/2/2009   0.114578
2/3/2009   0.114578
2/4/2009   0.114578
2/5/2009   0.114578
2/6/2009   0.114578
2/9/2009   0.114578
2/10/2009  0.114578
2/11/2009  0.114578
2/12/2009  0.114578
2/13/2009  0.114578
```

Putting drawdowns and the Maximum Drawdown (MDD) together in a dataframe so you can compare the result:

```
>> df_dd =  pd.concat([drawdown, drawdown.expanding().max()], axis=1)

>> df_dd.columns = ['drawdown', 'MDD'] 

>> df_dd
           drawdown       MDD
1/2/2009   0.000000  0.000000
1/5/2009   0.000000  0.000000
1/6/2009   0.000000  0.000000
1/7/2009   0.032432  0.032432
1/8/2009   0.027035  0.032432
1/9/2009   0.046343  0.046343
1/12/2009  0.065136  0.065136
1/13/2009  0.064114  0.065136
1/14/2009  0.094742  0.094742
1/15/2009  0.082399  0.094742
1/16/2009  0.073399  0.094742
1/20/2009  0.114578  0.114578
1/21/2009  0.083450  0.114578
1/22/2009  0.096837  0.114578
1/23/2009  0.090154  0.114578
1/26/2009  0.082957  0.114578
1/27/2009  0.075759  0.114578
1/28/2009  0.049007  0.114578
1/29/2009  0.071657  0.114578
1/30/2009  0.095336  0.114578
2/2/2009   0.095601  0.114578
2/3/2009   0.077340  0.114578
2/4/2009   0.077347  0.114578
2/5/2009   0.058830  0.114578
2/6/2009   0.034137  0.114578
2/9/2009   0.035688  0.114578
2/10/2009  0.070687  0.114578
2/11/2009  0.068379  0.114578
2/12/2009  0.066585  0.114578
2/13/2009  0.070709  0.114578
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the code. It is a bit unclear

Comment: Added more comments. You have more info in the links.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex_MN

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a column with the cumulative return, it is pretty straight forward: you want to get the max value at any given point and compare it with the actual cumulative return of the rows occurring only after such point.

Then, if you take the the lowest value, you get the maximum drawdown of the array.

```
import pandas as import pd
import numpy as np

def max_drawdown(arr: pd.Series) -> int:
    return np.min(arr / arr.expanding().max()) - 1
```

In case you need to calculate the cumulative return first, using log makes it pretty straight forward:

```
import numpy as np

final['log_return'] = np.log(1 + final['Returns'])
final['log_cum_return'] = np.cumsum(final['log_return'])
final['cumulative_returns'] = np.expm1(final['log_cum_return'])
```